OpenWRT extend wifi with different settings
I am trying to set up a router which allows my team to connect devices to, so that we may test various network setups and configurations.
In the office we have a Wi-Fi network that anyone may connect to. There is no wired option.
Is it possible to have a router running OpenWRT that connects to the office Wi-Fi, and extends it by providing a second Wi-Fi network, but allows us to change attributes of the second network. For example an attribute I am interested in changing is the Wi-Fi networks country code.

I did some reading, but I want confirmation of my understanding:

It seems it is possible to change the country code (see here).
Wi-Fi can be extended the way I describe: See here


Are you wanting the router to work in Mesh mode? In Mesh mode the router has to accept the settings of the mesh network and so modifying the country code will probably not work. Instead, connect the OpenWRT device directly to the office network, hard wired, and make your settings. NOTE: This assumes you have permission and are allowed to do this. Your question implies a certain level of consent, but does not explicitly state this, and adding disallowed devices to a network CAN be a "resume generating event".

OpenWRT supports guest networks which will be separate from the normal network. It will NOT be possible to change the country code.  The country code is built-into the firmware of the radio. The page you linked to references this fact.
